# Toggle hide/show between two divs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a link working that will toggle hide/show between two divs. Nothing strange and I've seen a lot of examples where this has been done.
My basic html structure is as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="tog_A">
   <div id="tog_B">
</div>

<a href="#" id="link">Toggle</a>
```

And CSS:

```
#tog_A {
  display:block;
}
#tog_A {
  display:block;
}
```

However, when I add the different solutions that I have found there seems to be a conflict with some other JavaScript code my site uses.
I'm a real n00b when it comes to JavaScript so perhaps someone can point me in the right direction and maybe help me combine my existing code with the new.

Existing JavaScrip that seems to be in conflict:

```
//Load when dom ready
jQuery(function() {
// click listener for anchors
jQuery(document).on("click",'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {

// prevent click and side effects 
    e.preventDefault();

// do the scroll
  jQuery('body, html').animate({
    scrollTop : jQuery(this.hash).offset().top
  });

//change state of button
var oldHash = jQuery(this.hash).attr("id").split("-");
var oldNr = parseInt(oldHash[1],10);
var nrOfAllSections = jQuery('[id^="section-"]').length;
var nr = oldNr == nrOfAllSections ? 1 : oldNr+1;
if(oldNr == nrOfAllSections) {
  jQuery(this).text("Top ▴");
    } else {
  jQuery(this).text("Down ▾");
    }
var newHash = "#"+oldHash[0]+"-"+ nr;
jQuery(this).attr("href", newHash);
});

jQuery(document).on('click', "#scrollToInfo", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var nrOfAllSections = jQuery('[id^="section-"]').length;
   var hrefHash = "#section-" + nrOfAllSections;
   var ypos = jQuery(hrefHash).offset().top;
   window.scrollTo(0, ypos);
   jQuery('a#scrollToBottom').text("Top ▴").attr("href", "#section-1");
 });

});
```

Comment: I'm confused to why you need help. *"I've seen a lot of examples where this has been done"* Why not just use those examples? Obviously it will mean editing some of it to fit your own source code....

Answer (score 0):

Use this technique

```
  $("#link").click(function () {
       if ($("#tog_A").is(":visible")) {
         $("#tog_A").hide();
         $("#tog_B").show();
      } else {
        $("#tog_B").hide();
        $("#tog_A").show();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
 <script>
  var toggle = function() {
  var mydiv = document.getElementById('tog_A');
  var mydiv2 = document.getElementById('tog_B');
  if (mydiv.style.display === 'none' || mydiv.style.display === '' ||      mydiv2.style.display === 'none' || mydiv2.style.display === '')
   mydiv.style.display = 'block';
    mydiv2.style.display = 'block';

 else
   mydiv.style.display = 'none'
   mydiv2.style.display= 'none'
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="tog_A" style="display:none;">
   <div id="tog_B" style="display:none;" >
</div>

  <a href="#" onclick="toggle();" id="link">Toggle</a>
<body>
```

Comment: This works on my website, I use it for if people are viewing my website on mobile works fine for me.